# Getting Unexpected DMA error in Flutter when using video_player, better_player, and chewie

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

Im trying to play a video. Im getting the following error:

```
E/gralloc_ranchu( 2305): updateHostColorBuffer: Unexpected DMA
E/        ( 2305): lockAndWriteDma: ERROR: No DMA context bound!
```

Im just using the sample code from https://pub.dev/packages/chewie and the video player just shows a green screen and doesnt do anything. Any ideas?

EDIT: Some more comments that may help?

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl(10386): Release 3310ed3 [ExoPlayerLib/2.12.1] [generic_x86_arm, AOSP on IA Emulator, Google, 28] [goog.exo.core]
D/SurfaceUtils(10386): disconnecting from surface 0xd36c1008, reason disconnectFromSurface
I/ExoPlayerImpl(10386): Release d52c17 [ExoPlayerLib/2.12.1] [generic_x86_arm, AOSP on IA Emulator, Google, 28] [goog.exo.core]
D/SurfaceUtils(10386): disconnecting from surface 0xd2c83808, reason disconnectFromSurface
I/ExoPlayerImpl(10386): Init d3251ff [ExoPlayerLib/2.12.1] [generic_x86_arm, AOSP on IA Emulator, Google, 28]
I/OMXClient(10386): IOmx service obtained
D/SurfaceUtils(10386): connecting to surface 0xd1be1008, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec(10386): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setting surface generation to 10635268
D/SurfaceUtils(10386): disconnecting from surface 0xd1be1008, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils(10386): connecting to surface 0xd1be1008, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
E/ACodec  (10386): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -1010
I/ACodec  (10386): codec does not support config priority (err -1010)
I/OMXClient(10386): IOmx service obtained
I/ACodec  (10386): codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
I/ACodec  (10386): codec does not support config operating rate (err -2147483648)
D/MediaCodec(10386): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] setting dataspace on output surface to #104
I/om.example.kli(10386): Background concurrent copying GC freed 11055(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 769(50MB) LOS objects, 50% free, 5MB/10MB, paused 529us total 209.709ms
W/MapperHal(10386): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
```

Comment: I removed my previous answer about downgrading `targetSdkVersion` to 27 from 30 in `android/app/build.gradle`, because it stopped working on my end and I have no idea why. So it's clearly not a solution that works, at least not consistently. I've done a few things since it worked last time and I don't know which ones broke it again or why.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/76644) with no known workarounds at present. It might be helpful if you could also provide the video that you're trying to load for easier replication of the issue.